# mandoc installation problem

Tags: software-installation, compiling, source

I have downloaded `mandoc` from [mandoc | UNIX manpage compiler](http://mandoc.bsd.lv/). I execute these command in my Ubuntu 14.04 to install-

```
tar -xzvf mandoc.tar.gz
cd mandoc-1.14.3
./configure
```

Then `sudo make install` results as follows-

```
read.c:34:18: fatal error: zlib.h: No such file or directory
 #include <zlib.h>
                  ^
compilation terminated.
make: *** [read.o] Error 1
```

Now, how to solve this I don't know?

Comment: [Compilation error - missing zlib.h](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18148075/4023950)

Comment: @αғsнιη this is the same question and answer. should I delete my question?

Comment: Broken record time - your distribution really should have a package for this. Why are you compiling it?

Comment: @FaheemMitha It's available in Zesty, but not in Trusty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The program obviously makes use of `zlib`, a compression library, probably to be able to decompress compressed manual sources.

Depending on your Unix, you will need to install the `zlib` development files (headers etc.).  On Debian based Linux distributions, and Ubuntu, these come packaged in the `zlib1g-dev` package, for example.

Also, if your Unix already have `mandoc` available as a pre-compiled package, then use that rather than compiling it yourself.  See [the list of Unices here](http://mandoc.bsd.lv/ports.html) for example (list may be incomplete), and note that `mandoc` is sometimes known as `mdocml`.

On Ubuntu (Zesty or later, but not Trusty which the user asking the question is running):

```
apt-get install mandoc
```

Comment: `mandoc` is not in Ubuntu repository.

Comment: @BandaMuhammadAlHelal I just noticed that too. It's not in `trusty` but _is_ available in `zesty`. `zlib1g-dev` is available in `trusty` though.

Comment: `zlib1g-dev` is available yes. So, I think you should edit your answer.

Answer (score 1):

From mandoc's `INSTALL` file:

The following libraries are required:

> 1. **zlib** for decompressing gzipped manual pages.
> 2. The **fts**(3) directory traversion functions. If your system does not have them, the bundled compatibility version will be used, so you need
>      not worry in that case.  But be careful: old glibc versions of fts(3)
>      were known to be broken on 32bit platforms, see
>      https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=11460. That was
>      presumably fixed in glibc-2.23. If you run into that problem, set
>      "HAVE_FTS=0" in configure.local.
> 3. Marc Espie's **ohash**(3) library. If your system does not have it, the bundled compatibility version will be used, so you probably need not
>      worry about it.

You must install the corresponding development packages on your system.